# Как правильно обрабатывать сообщения от оконной функции?

Tags: c, winapi

Я пишу текстовый редактор на си и WinAPI. Надо ли запускать ядро проги через CreateThread(), чтобы оконная процедура справлялась с сообщениями? Я новичок в программировании, но, подозреваю, что это надо, иначе оконная процедура не будет справляться, ожидая завершения операций в ядре. Начал изучать многопоточность и пока остановился на том, что запущенная нить ядра будет создавать мутекс на время своей работы. После завершения работы над очередной порцией информации, нить будет завершаться, мутекс устанавливаться. И тогда очередное сообщение от процедуры главного окна сново будет запускать нить для обработки очередного сообщения, а мутекс будет сброшен. Верно ли я мыслю? Простите, если я чушь полную написал, я пока учусь.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про WinApi в целом. [Вот WinApi](http://www.uhlib.ru/kompyutery_i_internet/sistemnoe_programmirovanie_v_srede_windows/index.php), [вот ещё WinApi](http://wm-help.net/books-online/book/59464.html) и [вот про потоки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684254(v=vs.85).aspx) в Windows (На английском).

От себя скажу, что изначально у вас есть 1 нить исполнения (поток). Вы в праве делать все в ней, если будете успевать делать работу после приёма сообщения. Если ваше приложение начнёт фризить, т.е. главный поток занят, а сообщения поступают, то следует создать новый поток, синхронизировать с главным и дальше делать всю сложную работу в новом, а приём оставить в главном.

Comment: вот Вы написали: "следует создать новый поток, синхронизировать с главным и дальше делать всю сложную работу в новом". Вот я и спрашивал, подойдёт ли для этой цели мутекс?

Comment: @0Zerro, я предположил, что рас вы задали такой тривиальный вопрос, то следует дать более развёрнутый ответ.